# How to count active workflows in one object

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

Requirement:**-I need to count total Active workflows for each object** .
Like For account object how many active workflows are there..
Is there any quick way to achieve this(query or something like this).

Comment: I need a count only (number of wf rules for each Object).I dont want any metadata or info .

Answer (score 5):

**Metadata API**

This can be accomplished using the [listMetadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listmetadata.htm) operation on the Metadata API.

> This call retrieves property information about metadata components in your organization. Data is returned for the components that match the criteria specified in the queries parameter. The queries array can contain up to three ListMetadataQuery queries for each call. This call supports every metadata type: both top-level, such as CustomObject and ApexClass, and child types, such as CustomField and RecordType.

There is some sample **Java code** at the bottom of the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listmetadata.htm).

If your wanting to use **Apex** there is also a [wrapper library here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) you can use, along with a sample [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L234). The following is an Apex Metadata API (wrapper) example, but you'll find it in alignment with the requirement from other langauges such as Java and .Net.

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        
    MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
    queryWorkflow.type_x = 'Workflow';
    queries.add(queryWorkflow);     
    MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 25);
    for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties)
        System.debug(fileProperty.fullName);
```

**Tooling API**

There also seems to be support for [querying](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_rest_overview.htm) via the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/index.htm) the [Workflow object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_workflowrule.htm), which will likely give you more information than just the **FileProperties**. There is also an **Apex** wrapper for this API [here](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi).

Answer (score 1):

You could call the metadata api from apex and than process the output.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm